# No Request in iFrame Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, request

I've got an advent calendar for my website, inserted with an iFrame. Before the first of december, you connect to a test calendar, where you can change the date with a dropdown.

In firefox everything runs smoothly. A second request is generated, and the calendar thinks it 10th of december. But Chrome don't fire a second request.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend go [through these changes](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html) in Chrome regarding iframes

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that didn't change a thing. The partnered company itself sent a secure none samesite cookie. And just to be sure, I also did that in my code. No changes.